# Is there a specific word for the hallucinogic state one get's when feverish?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was a child, I once got those when in a serious febrile episode, caused by bacterial infection. I see that sometimes happens to children, but not adults.

My question is: is there a specific word for that?

In my language there's a specific name for delirium caused by fever, (at least elderly people around me had a name for that) so I wanted to know if there's such in English.

Apart from delirium, which is the obvious word that comes to mind, what *alternatives* might be there?

Comment: Is the Portuguese word for this fever delirium something other than *delírio*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes, there's that one, but elderly people often say one is *variando*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest we have is **[fever dream](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fever_dream)**.

> A usually frightening or unsettling dream caused by a fever; (in extended use) a heightened and often disconcerting vision, idea, etc.

Comment: Thanks, despite being an only approximate term, that's precisely what I intended to know.